# Better to wrap forms in divs or list items

Tags: forms, list, html

Is it best to wrap forms inputs in divs:

```
<div id="formContainer">
   <div>
       <label for="username">Username</label><input type="text" id="username">
   </div>
   <div>
       <label for="password">Password</label><input type="text" id="password">
   </div>
</div>
```

Or is it better to wrap in ul or ol list with list-style-type set to none

```
<ol id="formContainer">
   <li>
       <label for="username">Username</label><input type="text" id="username">
   </li>
   <li>
       <label for="password">Password</label><input type="text" id="password">
   </li>
</ol>
```

Or does it matter at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would opt with a definition list:

```
<dl>
    <dt><label for='name'>blah</label></dt>
    <dd><input type='text'></dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: is there a specific reason why definition list is a good option?

Answer (score 0):

I always use `table`s because that makes it so easy to align the fields.

Comment: I would rather not use tables